# google analytics op_scope for page tracking

Tags: google-analytics

Javascript Google Analytics provides a setCustomVar method that allows us to submit custom data that will appear on the reports.  I'm not clear on the opt_scope parameter however:

```
opt_scope   Optional. The scope used for the custom variable. Possible values are 1 for visitor-level, 2 for session-level, and 3 for page-level.
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setCustomVar

Where can I find more information about these three options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tracking Custom Variables](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables) has a good description of the custom variable scope in Google Analytics.

> Each of these three levels of interaction defines a specific scope of visitor engagement. This distinction is important to custom variables because each custom variable is restricted to a particular scope. For example, you might want to know the number of sessions where visitors removed an item from their shopping cart. For that particular case, you would define the custom variable to the session level, so that the entire session for that visitor is flagged as one in which items were removed from online carts.